# PAYPAL Direct Payment API Postal Code for Republic of Ireland

Tags: api, paypal, zip

The doDirectPayment API documentation on paypal states that ZIP/Postal Code is a required field, but Ireland doesn't currently use Postal Codes. 
Does anyone know if that documentation is still correct or does the API ignore ZIP for Irish addresses?

Comment: Have you tried the call without the field to see?

Comment: Thanks @Machavity - tried that now and answered my own question - it seems that the API ignores ZIP/Postcode for Ireland - I teft the field blank and received ACK: Success back from the API.